# Magento EE: reward point adjustment action definition

Tags: magento

In Magento EE's database, there is a table named `enterprise_reward_history` in which there exists a column named `action`. `action` has IDs of the reward point adjustment action types (e.g. 0: moderator action; 1: redemption; etc.), but I can't seem to find where the definitions are stored. I've mapped out most of them we have from IDs 1 - 11, but I'm still missing 5 and 10, and possibly ones beyond 11.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app/code/core/Enterprise/Reward/Model/Reward.php` they are constants:

```
const REWARD_ACTION_ADMIN               = 0;
const REWARD_ACTION_ORDER               = 1;
const REWARD_ACTION_REGISTER            = 2;
const REWARD_ACTION_NEWSLETTER          = 3;
const REWARD_ACTION_INVITATION_CUSTOMER = 4;
const REWARD_ACTION_INVITATION_ORDER    = 5;
const REWARD_ACTION_REVIEW              = 6;
const REWARD_ACTION_TAG                 = 7;
const REWARD_ACTION_ORDER_EXTRA         = 8;
const REWARD_ACTION_CREDITMEMO          = 9;
const REWARD_ACTION_SALESRULE           = 10;
const REWARD_ACTION_REVERT              = 11;
```